# How to traverse deque and search for an element?

Tags: c++, deque

i have a two deques that are defined like this

```
struct elem
{
    int key; elem* next;
}
*left = NULL, *right=NULL, *left2 = NULL, *right2 = NULL;
```

and a push and pop function

```
void push_front(int n, elem*&l, elem*&r)
{
    elem *p=left;
    left = new elem;
    left -> key=n;
    left -> next=p;
    if(right==NULL)
    {
        right = left;
    }
}

int pop_front(int &n, elem*&l, elem*&r)
{ 
    elem *p; 
if (left)  
{    
    n=left->key; 
    p=left;    
    left=left->next;
    if (left==NULL)
        right=NULL;    
    delete p;     
    return 1;
}   
else
    return 0;
}
```

I have to enter an integer that the search function will use. For some reason they gave me the requirement to pop the element first, check if it is equal to the entered number and repeat until we either find the element or if we have popped all elements from the first deque. Before the requirement I had done it like that but apparently it's not correct:

```
void search(int x)
{
    elem *y=left;
    while(y->key!=x)
    {
    if(y==right)
    {
        cout<<x<<" wasn't found, adding to front."<<endl;
        push_front(x);
        return;
    }
    y=y->next;
    }
    cout<<x<<" was found"<<endl;
    return;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.
And also no i can't use the deque library or std::find or anything like that.

Comment: [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) - why wouldn't you?

Comment: It is a requirement that i not use it... I did this ages ago using std::find but i'm literally not allowed to use it.

Comment: *i have a two deques that are defined like this* -- What you are showing us looks more like a singly-linked list, not a deque.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the both functions `push_front` and `pop_front` have typos. Within the functions instead of identifiers `left` and `right` you have to use identifiers of parameters `l` and `r`.

```
void push_front(int n, elem*&l, elem*&r)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    elem *p=left;
            ^^^^^
    //...
```

And you should not define global variables left, right, left2, and right2. The functions shall not depend on the global variables.

A function like search should do only one thing: report whether the element is present in the list or not present.

So the function should be defined like

```
bool search( const elem * &l, int x )
{
    const elem *current = l;

    while ( current != nullptr && current->key != x ) current = current->next;

    return current != nullptr;
}
```

Based on the return value of the function you can either add the value to the list or do something else.

If to use an auxiliary list (that is inefficient) because you may traverse the list only using the functions `pop_front` and `push_front` then the function can look like

```
bool search( elem * &l, elem * &r, int x )
{
    elem *l2 = nullptr, *r2 = nullptr;

    bool success = false;

    if ( l != nullptr )
    {
        do 
        {
            int key;

            pop_front( key, l, r );
            push_front( key, l2, r2 );

            success = key == x;
        } while ( !success && l != nullptr );
    }

    while ( l2 != nullptr )
    {
        pop_front( key, l2, r2 );
        push_front( key, l, r );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct elem
{
    int key; 
    elem *next;
};

void push_front( int n, elem * &l, elem * &r )
{
    l = new elem { n, l };

    if ( r == nullptr ) r = l;
}

bool pop_front( int &n, elem * &l, elem * &r )
{ 
    bool success = l != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        n = l->key;

        elem *tmp = l;

        l = l->next;

        if ( l == nullptr ) r = nullptr;

        delete tmp;
    }

    return success;
}   


bool search( elem * &l, elem * &r, int x )
{
    elem *l2 = nullptr, *r2 = nullptr;

    bool success = false;

    if ( l != nullptr )
    {
        do 
        {
            int key;

            pop_front( key, l, r );
            push_front( key, l2, r2 );

            success = key == x;
        } while ( !success && l != nullptr );
    }

    while ( l2 != nullptr )
    {
        pop_front( key, l2, r2 );
        push_front( key, l, r );
    }

    return success;
}

int main() 
{
    elem *left = nullptr, *right = nullptr;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; --i )
    {
        push_front( i, left, right );
    }

    if ( !search( left, right, 0 ) )
    {
        push_front( 0, left, right );
    }

    while ( left != nullptr )
    {
        int key;

        pop_front( key, left, right );

        std::cout << key << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

That is if 0 is not found in the formed list it is pushed front on the list. The program output shows the result.

Answer (score 0):

> How to traverse deque ...

This depends highly on what data structure is used to implement the double ended queue. `std::deque` for example is implemented as a linked list of arrays. You traverse the list like you would traverse a linked list, except at each node you traverse the array.

Regardless, traversal of a data structure is usually implemented in C++ by defining an iterator class. Given an iterator, traversal can be implemented like this:

```
current = beginning_of_the_range;
last    = end_of_the_range;
for (; current != last; ++current) {
    // current points to current element here
}
```

> ```
> struct elem
> {
>     int key; elem* next;
> }
> ```

It appears that you have implemented your double ended queue using a singly linked list. An iterator for a singly linked list can be implemented like this:

- Store pointer to current node in the iterator. Let us call it `node`.
- Indirection of the iterator can be implemented as `return node->key;`
- To move to the next element, do `node = node->next;`.
- To check if iterator is equal, `return node == other.node;`.
- Iterator representing the end can be represented as nullptr, or using a sentinel node.

> ... and search for an element?

Once you've implemented the traversal, you can use linear search.